# Adding time value in datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to add time in my date picker when date is selected.
I am able to select date but time is not added with date
I am using following code.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '2001:2020',
        minDate: new Date(2011, 1 - 1, 1),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate, "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy" + " 12:00 AM ");
        }
    });
    $("#endDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '2001:2020',
        minDate: new Date(2011, 1 - 1, 1),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate, "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy" + " 11:59 PM ");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use a different widget, specifically designed for date *and* time: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: @Manish hi. please check my answer and pick me as chosen answer if it solved your question. thanks